# Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'sha256 HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Hi there im getting Refused to apply inline style because

> it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'sha256-0hAheEzaMe6uXIKV4EehS9pu1am1lj/KnnzrOYqckXk='". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-Z8YLBGErPFDZMNa4AdvZzfK5mRwF+kDSfDQyfyxIOdk='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

i have a react app but im getting the error in HTML document. i have tried the previous suggestions but am still getting the error.

[image] [image]

Comment: if you are using localhost, try to take the build folder and run it.

Comment: thank you, i did try this but unfortunately I still got the same error.